# Flutter функция on tap

Tags: flutter

Я новичок во flutter, решил создать приложение магазин. У меня есть 10 категории, создал кастом виджет где присутствует функия on tap. Возможно ли с одной функции on tap направить на эти 10 категории?

```
class ListOfCategory extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListOfCategoryState createState() => _ListOfCategoryState();
}

class _ListOfCategoryState extends State<ListOfCategory> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        // padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40, right: 40),
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, left: 40, right: 40),
            child: Image.asset('assets/dafna_logo.png'),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 15),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Wrap(
              children: <Widget>[
                _categoryTap('name'),
                _categoryTap('name'),
                _categoryTap('name'),
                _categoryTap('name'),
                _categoryTap('name'),
                _categoryTap('name'),
                _categoryTap('name'),
                _categoryTap('name'),
                _categoryTap('name'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget _categoryTap(String _nameCategory) {
  return InkWell(
    onTap: () {},
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 120,
            width: 120,
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
          Container(
            width: 120,
            height: 35,
            // color: Colors.red,
            child: Text(
              _nameCategory,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: `Возможно ли с одной функции on tap направить на эти 10 категории?` Можно поподробнее описать, что вы хотите сделать. Не совсем понятно...

Comment: Есть виджет  _categoryTap, у него одна функция on tap, в основной ветке я размножил этот виджет, как сделать так чтоб в функции on tap дать путь к 10ти другим виджетам( то есть категориям)? Можно сделать 10шт InkWell виджетов и в каждой прописать функцию on tap,  но это увеличит весь код, может это и нормально с точки зрения написания кода. но все таки может можно уменьшить.

Comment: ответил на вопрос, проверяйте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для навигации в приложении в Flutter есть [Navigator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html), который позволяет перемещаться по имени класса или имени route (маршрута).

Если правильно понял вопрос, тогда будет так:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      // Начало приложения
      initialRoute: '/',
      // Список всех возможных маршрутов приложения
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => ListOfCategory(),
        '/second': (context) => SecondScreen(),
      },
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class ListOfCategory extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListOfCategoryState createState() => _ListOfCategoryState();
}

class _ListOfCategoryState extends State<ListOfCategory> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, left: 40, right: 40),
            child: Image.asset('assets/dafna_logo.png'),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 15),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Wrap(
              children: <Widget>[
                _categoryTap('second', '/second'),
                _categoryTap('name2', '/...'),
                _categoryTap('name3', '/...'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _categoryTap(String _nameCategory, String route) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, route),
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 120,
              width: 120,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            Container(
              width: 120,
              height: 35,
              child: Text(
                _nameCategory,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// Другой экран
class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Page"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/'),
          child: Text('Go back!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

Данный пример не идеальный, если хотите сделать лучше, [то вот пример как это можно сделать](https://www.filledstacks.com/post/navigate-without-build-context-in-flutter-using-a-navigation-service/).

[Хорошие статьи которые вам помогут разобраться с навигацией.](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Такой вопрос, в вэб разработке есть админка, есть ли такое в мобильной разработке? как я понимаю это бэкенд, может посоветуете что нибудь в этом направлении?

Comment: @AndreyKhan да есть, и не только в мобильной разработке, а везде. Это зависит от архитектуры приложения и его взаимодействия с бэкендом (SQL, API). У вас скорее всего есть БД с которым данное мобильное приложение будет взаимодействовать, вам необходимо чтобы эта БД после авторизации выдавала информацию о пользователе (имя, email, админ). На основе проверки принадлежности к админ группе и строиться админка в приложении (`if(admin){ // Админ пункты меню}`). Также стоит помнить и про навигацию (там тоже необходимо проверять).

Comment: Для работы с Sql напрямую есть такие плагины: [mysql1](https://pub.dev/packages/mysql1), [sqljocky5](https://pub.dev/packages/sqljocky5), если через бекенд в виде php: [логин](https://flutter-examples.com/flutter-online-user-login-using-php-mysql-api/), [регистрация](https://flutter-examples.com/flutter-online-user-registration-using-php-mysql-server/).

Comment: @AndreyKhan если вам подошел ответ, его можно отметить галочкой (слева от ответа), чтобы закрыть вопрос.

Comment: Если Вас не затруднит ответьте на еще один вопрос. в ecomm web добавление товара происходит через админку, который добавляется на сайт. в мобильном приложении такая же реализация или же переписывать код с добавлением??

Comment: Все зависит от вашего бекенда и подхода в разработке. Данный вопрос следует задать отдельно, приложив к нему структуру БД (как минимум пользователей с адм. и товаров), код бекенд (для управления таврами) и код приложения на Flutter.

Comment: Если у вас есть доступ к API  или SQL, можно обойтись без бекенда и работать с ними на прямую.